# how to configure multiple IP's on multiple NIC cards on same server

Tags: linux-networking

I have a CentOS7 server with integrated 4 NIC cards. Eth0 is setup for public IP and works just fine servicing an apache web server. My intent is to setup the second NIC card with its own different public IP to serve as a ntpd server. Back story is the server that's running the ntpd server (with its own IP) is going away. And I want to co-host the ntpd services on the same server as the web server.

Any lessons learned on how to setup the ifcfg-eth1 to not screw with the routing of eth0? The IP's are on the same subnet, same gateway, same netmask.

No VMs. Just bare metal.

Many thanks for any lessons learned or what to watch out for. If you have achieved this already, would you mind posting your ifcfg-eth*? Thanks.

--Robert

Comment: You don't even need the second NIC for that. Just add the IP address to the first NIC.

Comment: Using a second NIC in the same LAN (on the Internet side) can expose you to unexpected effects (ARP flux). Using it on a different LAN gets you multi-homing instead with its own complexity. Do you really need it, or only the extra IP address? And is this address in the same LAN as the other(s)?